# Magento 2: Not able to save custom dropdown product attribute value programatically

Tags: custom-attributes, magento2.2.3

I am using magento 2.2.3, and created a dropdown attribute "wholeseler" in admin area with some attribute values.
Now I want to update the "wholeseler" attribute value programmatically.

I am using below code but not working

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

include('app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstraps = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$object_Manager = $bootstraps->getObjectManager();
$app_state = $object_Manager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$app_state->setAreaCode('frontend');

// Instance of object manager
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory');

$productResourceModelFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\ProductFactory');

$productId = "84";

$product = $productFactory->create()->load($productId);
$product->setWhol("rub");
$product->save();

$productResource = $productResourceModelFactory->create();
$productResource->saveAttribute($product, 'whol'); 
echo "whol added ".$product->getId()."\n";
```

Please share any alternate solution that work for save the attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$eavConfig = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
$attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'your_attribute_code');
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
foreach($options as $option) {
    if($option['label'] == "your text"){
        // $option['value'] - your value
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share code example if you have for M2?

Comment: answer was updated

Comment: but this only for example, it can be not the best way to do that, i copied this from another same questions... look in the model, may be you can get "integer" values withour listing of all...

Answer (score 0):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$eavConfig = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
$attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'your_attribute_code');
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
$value = '';
foreach($options as $option) {
    if($option['label'] == "your text"){
        $value = $option['value'];
    }
}
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // instance of object manager
$product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$prod = $product->loadByAttribute('sku', 'sku');

$attr_code = 'your_attribute_code';
$prod->setCustomAttribute($attr_code, $value);
$prod->save();
```